# Elastic beanstalk and Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible deploy an Angular 2 application on Elastic beanstalk?
I'm trying to packaging an application but I have the following problems:

1. npm is not installed on the machine, I had to install it manually connecting via ssh, I'm wondering if there is an automated way to install it.
2. The version od node was wrong, I had to manually update too, also in this case I'm wondering if there is an automated way to update it.
3. When finally the application starts on the port 8081 using browser-sync, I get an error because this port seems already to be in use.

Comment: hey @magemello, did you ever find out the solution to this. I seem to be running into #3. I keep getting an 8081 port in use, even though I'm manually setting the port to 3001, via process.env.PORT